# View Binding Issue Using Data Returned From Factory

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

When I am calling AngularJs factory method to bind a list of months with static array then it is working fine. But when I am using MVC Controller to return same data then $scope.months  not binding list.

While the XHR response has the same data. I don't know what is the issue.

Following is code snippet :

**HomeController.css**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAllMonths()
{
    List<Month> monthList = new JsonRepository<Month>().GetAll();
    var output =  Json(monthList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return output;
}
```

**AngularJs Factory**

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    var app = angular.module("CommonFactory", []);

    app.factory("DataFactory", ["$http",DataFactory]);

    /*DI For Factory*/
    //DataFactory.$inject = ["$http"];



    //Factories callBack functions

    function DataFactory($http) {
        return {
            getMonths: function () {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/Home/GetAllMonths'
                }).then(function(response){
                       return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

**AngularJs Controller**

```
//Modules With Controllers
var app = angular.module("PublicModule", [])
                 .controller("HomeController", homeController);


//Dependency Injection
homeController.$inject = ["$scope","$http", "DataFactory", "DataService"];


//Functions
function homeController($scope,$http, DataFactory,DataServic) {
    $scope.headingText = "Home";

    $scope.months = DataFactory.getMonths();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the data from the promise with its `.then` method:

```
//Functions
function homeController($scope,$http, DataFactory,DataService) {
    $scope.headingText = "Home";

    DataFactory.getMonths().then(function(data) {
        $scope.months = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks georgeawg! 

It's working good. But how to move this logic into getMonth() function of  factory js

Comment: I/O in JavaScript is non-blocking. That means that the code does not wait for the data to come back from the server. Instead the success/rejection function is held by the  $q service and executed at a later time. For more infromation see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).